# Need help selecting an item from a dropdown list in HP UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I need some help with selecting a value from a dropdown list. The dropdown is a WebElement, and the flow works well up to the point where the value should be selected.

My code is as follows:

```
.Browser("Browser").Page("PageName").WebElement("DropDownList").Click
.WebList("ListOfItems").Select(itemToSelect)
```

Note: itemToSelect is the name of the item that needs to be selected from the list, which is being passed as a parameter within the function.

When running the code, I get an unspecified error.

The weird thing is that before the error is thrown, I can see the value being selected from the list in the browser, as upon selecting it, some fields in the form change. Also, if I press "Skip" in the error message panel, the process goes on as if nothing happened.

I am certain the error comes from `.WebList("ListOfItems").Select(itemToSelect)` but I do not know what to do in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your replies.
The issue turned out to be due to the object not being added well to the repository.
It was eventually fixed by adding it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It works for me.

```
StrAllItems = Split(Browser("name:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebList("name:=.*").GetRoProperty("all items"),";")

For intCounter = Lbound(strAllItems) to Ubound(strAllItems)-1


   If Browser("name:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebList("name:=.*").GetItem(intCounter)= "SomeValue" Then
            Browser("name:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebList("name:=.*").Select (intCounter)
            Exit For

   End If

Next
```

Please let me know if this help.

Answer (score 0):

If the test behaves correctly and you're just getting an superfluous error you can just ignore this specific error. It's best of course to understand where the error comes from, you should probably contact MicroFocus support but in the meantime you can turn off error handling for the offending line.

```vbs
Browser("Browser").Page("PageName").WebElement("DropDownList").Click

On Error Resume Next ' turn off error handling
Browser("Browser").Page("PageName").WebList("ListOfItems").Select(itemToSelect)
On Error Goto 0 ' turn error handling back on
```

BTW, I changed your code a bit to make it valid, I assume this is what your code really looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Possible timing issue: You might need to wait for the hole list to appear before you select the item.

Often, the item exists, but the app is still updating its GUI.

Whenever you access the GUI with UFT while the app is not idle (f.e. not ready for user input because it is still updating its HTML), you might get all kinds of strange results, including unexpected errors, hangs, instability.

So how do you wait for the list to be complete? I don't know, because it heavily depends on the way your app is refreshing its GUI. You need to explore that, and integrate some synchronization code that waits for the right condition to be met.
Unfortunately, this is a hell of a job sometimes.

A suitable workaround (and a good way to verify if my hyphothesis is correct) might be to insert a large delay between the first click and the list item selection click. (A quick way to do a similar thing is to single-step through the code.) If that does not generate any error or issues, you can be pretty sure it is what I describe, and you can experiment with lower delay durations to find a good value.